# Calling octave .m file from a C++ project, undefined reference to octave::feval error

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++, octave

I am trying to call octave .m file from a c++ project, for that I am using this [octave example](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Standalone-Programs.html). I have Octave-5.1.0.0 installed on windows server 2012 and using g++ (gcc) 7.4.0 to compile.

I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `octave::feval(std::string const&, octave_value_list const&,int)'
relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `octave::feval(std::string const&, octave_value_list const&, int)'
undefined reference to `Array<std::string>::nil_rep()'
relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Array<std::string>::nil_rep()'
undefined reference to `Array<std::string>::resize_fill_value() const'
undefined reference to `Array<std::string>::resize_fill_value() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I read online that one possible reason for this may be conflicting values of the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro.

so I add the following code at the beginning of my .cpp file

```
#ifdef   _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
#undef   _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
#endif

#define  _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI  0
```

Here are the header files I am including:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Octave/oct.h> 
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/toplev.h>
#include <octave/interpreter.h>
#include <octave/Array.h>
```

and I use the following command to link

```
mkoctfile --link-stand-alone -o test test.o -loctinterp -loctave -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

Comment: How do you produce the test.o file?

Comment: I used `g++ -c -IC:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\include\octave-5.1.0 -o test.o test.cpp` to get the test.o

Comment: Just a simple idea: the example shows how does the mkoctfile build the executable from C++ sources. Why not to try it without using g++ directly?

Comment: I am going to call .m files from a bigger C++ project eventually. My final project will have multiple source files and using various libraries such as ODBC. Therefore, I made a make file to incorporate all these together with mkoctfile. I have tried with simpler example and it was working, the problem starts when using `feval` or `octave_value_list`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov When I try to compile and build the `test.exe` by the command in the example I got [this error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6ni0685cxfcdm5/error.txt?dl=0).